# Supercluster and vector tiles

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to take a set of points, use [supercluster](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster/) to create an index, and query that index for vector tiles. Things mostly work as expected, but when the tiles are loaded into Mapbox GL JS they appear to be the wrong size or incomplete:

[image]

I have tried adjusting the `extent` setting of supercluster with no success. Mapbox GL JS also throws a warning that the layer "clusters" does not follow v2 of the vector tile spec, but changing the code per [this suggestion](https://github.com/mapbox/vt-pbf/issues/12#issuecomment-270631200) did not make a difference in the rendering.

You can find all the code demonstrating this behavior [here](https://gist.github.com/jczaplew/2e2a243dbe8d4dd8a075e75f3a4366d5)